# Is the site activity worrisome?

Tags: support, site-promotion

The [Arabic language proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language) was shut down for "not sufficient activity" after 61 days in beta.

[Our Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language) looks frighteningly similar, although we seem to have more active users.

[image: arabic vs latin proposals]

Is this something we should be worried about?

Comment: Of course only staff can weigh in here, but the big difference I see is that that site had basically one active user (no one else over 700 rep), while we have a nice core group.  Still, point taken.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those Area 51 stats for Arabic are slightly... skewed. See, just before that site shut down, there was a small burst of questions from a couple users hoping that they could help keep the site alive that, well, didn't work. Before that burst, their stats were much lower, and activity was almost non-existent. They weren't even maintaining the 1 question-per-day mark for 1-2 weeks, and I believe there was a period of 3-4 days where they got *no* questions at all.

But the bigger problem surrounding the Arabic site was that no one was willing to step up and be a moderator. We couldn't gather the three required candidates. Coupled with the very low activity, the site looked pretty dead. There were just a couple users answering every question that rolled in over time, and not much else going on.

Latin isn't experiencing either of these problems. It's consistently getting *at least* 1 question every single day, and most of the time more than one. In fact, *most* beta sites usually sit around the 1-3 questions per day mark for quite some time. To pull some random examples out of a hat:

- [3D Printing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing) has been around for 100+ days and gets 1 question per day.
- [Lifehacks](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64409/lifehacks) has been around for 500+ days and gets 2.5 questions per day.
- [Sports](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports) has been around for over 1,500+ days and gets 2.6 questions per day.

If you're at or above the 1 mark, then that stat probably isn't going to raise many eyebrows. What's much more important is that **we have three moderators who stepped up to lead the site**. There's a *community* of users growing here that is interested in Latin as well as maintaining this site, rather than just a couple users who don't want to let it die.

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance!